# yii actions of single controller without authentication/authorization

Tags: php, yii

I'm using yii-powered app as backend of public API. I created `controllers/ApiController` class with `actionTest` method and trying to get some data by url `domain.ltd/api/test` without authorization by login/pass which usually need for another controllers (SiteController, for example). How can I do this?

I think there are few variants:

1. Setup route /api/* for guest access using authManager (?)
2. Something magic with UserIdentity class...

Comment: not sure if this is going to help, but you can just set the rights in the access rules of the controller...

Comment: ...it's basically what you'll find in @Justinas's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow anyone to access that page, just specify that in rules of controller (similar to login page, as you can access it without logging in)

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return [
        [
            'allow',
            'actions' => ['test'],
            'users' => ['*'],
        ],
        ['deny', // deny all users
            'users' => ['*'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: aren't those supposed to be normal brackets instead of square ones...?

Comment: @webeno in PHP >= 5.4 it's allowed to use short array tags. It will be error in lower versions